# pinescript lines only 10 bars long

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Hey thanks for reading my question.
I wondered how to make it so lines are only 10 bars long but won't get deleted when a new line is generated.

So I would like the script to draw a line from close to close every 10 bars, but right now it draws the lines, but they are not 10 bars long, they keep going indefinitely.

```
// Get the close price for the current bar and the 10th bar ago
current_close = close
past_close = close[10]

// Only plot the line every 10 bars
if bar_index % 10 == 0
    // Plot a line from the close of the 10th bar ago to the close of the current bar
    line_obj = line.new(bar_index - 10, past_close, bar_index, current_close, color=color.red, width=2, extend=extend.right)
    // Set the line's X location to keep it exactly 10 bars long
    line.set_xloc(line_obj, bar_index - 10, bar_index, xloc.bar_index)

// Hide the line after 10 bars
var line line_obj = na
if bar_index % 10 == 0
    if not na(line_obj)
        line.delete(line_obj)
    line_obj := line.new(bar_index - 19, past_close, bar_index - 10, current_close, color=color.red, width=2)
else
    // If the line hasn't been plotted, set the line_obj variable to na
    line_obj := na
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the extend parameter set to extend.right that will make the bar extended to the right until the end of the chart. You will need to delete that from your code if you want your lines to stop